# How to call a method after the user completes watching a video ad in flutter?

Tags: flutter, admob

i used **firebase admob** plugin to show the ads. I was implemented rewarded video ads. I want to implement when we click on button this shows ads and after completing the ads we go on next page with some value. I used this

```
RewardedVideoAd.instance
.show()
.whenComplete(uploadData(someData));
```

However, this does not work.
After that I created this method and used it but this is also not working

```
  Future myVideo(var myNumber) async {
  await RewardedVideoAd.instance.show();
  uploadData(somedata);
}
```

anyone know how to create this after succesful completed video ads call method or we go on next page until not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add rewarded video listener and in that you may add your method after completing your ads like that

```
    RewardedVideoAd.instance.listener =
      (RewardedVideoAdEvent event, {String rewardType, int rewardAmount}) {
       if (event == RewardedVideoAdEvent.rewarded) {
          setState(() {
            _coins += rewardAmount;
             uploadData(someData);
           });
        } else if (event == RewardedVideoAdEvent.completed) {
          setState(() {
           uploadData(someData);
           });
        } else if (event == RewardedVideoAdEvent.closed) {
          setState(() {
           uploadData(someData);
           });
        }
     };
```